# How i can access an object in php

Tags: php

Please see this code below:

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($s->channel);$i++){
    echo "--->".$ChannelName = $s->channel[$i]->{'display-name'};
    $arrChannelName[] = $ChannelName;
}

print_r($arrChannelName);
```

This return me output as Object instead of an array as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [lang] => dk
                )

            [0] => DR1 DK
        )

)
```

Anybody please help...!!!

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you have an array of objects of type SimpleXMLElement. Your array has a length of one and key 0 is mapped to the SimpleXMLElement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array("somearray" => array(6 => 5, 13 => 9, "a" => 42));

echo $arr["somearray"][6];    // 5
```

Like this , you can read that object array.

Or

You can use stdclass

http://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-Object-To-Array-With-PHP.html